Xamarin forms iOS app failed to launch on an iPad - rejected by App Review
Our iOS app update was submitted to App Store for review. It's been rejected with the following reason:

Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness
We were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch. We have
attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.
Review device details:

Device type: iPad Air (5th generation)
OS version: iOS 17.4.1

The crash log meta data:  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000,
0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGABRT"},
"termination" :
{"flags":0,"code":6,"namespace":"SIGNAL","indicator":"Abort trap:
6","byProc":"tecommobile.iOS","byPid":80465},   "asi" :
{"libsystem_c.dylib":["abort() called"]},   "faultingThread" : 0

The crash stack:
Hardware Model:      iPad13,16
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native(?))
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
OS Version:          iPhone OS 17.4.1 (21E236)
Release Type:        User
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0
Thread 0 name:  tid_103
Thread 0 Crashed:
0    libsystem_kernel.dylib                  0x1e5b8e974 __pthread_kill + 8
1    libsystem_pthread.dylib                 0x1f95cd0ec pthread_kill + 268
2    libsystem_c.dylib                       0x1a5647c14 __abort + 136
3    libsystem_c.dylib                       0x1a5647b8c abort + 192
4    tecommobile.iOS                         0x10652acbc xamarin_find_protocol_wrapper_type + 56372412 (runtime.m:1194)
5    tecommobile.iOS                         0x1064112fc mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook + 55218940 (exception.c:1299)
6    tecommobile.iOS                         0x1063aed14 mono_handle_exception_internal + 54816020 (mini-exceptions.c:2783)
7    tecommobile.iOS                         0x1063ad6e8 mono_handle_exception + 54810344 (mini-exceptions.c:3107)
8    tecommobile.iOS                         0x1063a40fc mono_arm_throw_exception + 54771964 (exceptions-arm64.c:403)
9    tecommobile.iOS                         0x10351571c throw_exception + 172
10   tecommobile.iOS                         0x103258c9c System_Runtime_ExceptionServices_ExceptionDispatchInfo_Throw + 44
11   tecommobile.iOS                         0x10325eca4 System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncMethodBuilderCore__c__ThrowAsyncb__7_0_object + 84
12   tecommobile.iOS                         0x1043a2a4c Foundation_NSAsyncSynchronizationContextDispatcher_Apply + 21211724 (NSAction.cs:176)
13   tecommobile.iOS                         0x1034a8810 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 272
14   tecommobile.iOS                         0x1063bf44c mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 54883404 (mini-runtime.c:3191)
15   tecommobile.iOS                         0x10646bd88 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 55590280 (object.c:3220)
16   tecommobile.iOS                         0x10646f20c mono_runtime_invoke + 55603724 (object.c:3107)
17   tecommobile.iOS                         0x103039db0 native_to_managed_trampoline_8(objc_object*, objc_selector*, _MonoMethod**, unsigned int) + 859568 (registrar.m:365)
18   tecommobile.iOS                         0x10303f714 -[__MonoMac_NSAsyncSynchronizationContextDispatcher xamarinApplySelector] + 882452 (registrar.m:9583)
19   Foundation                              0x19c5fd630 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 264
20   CoreFoundation                          0x19d6c962c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
21   CoreFoundation                          0x19d6c88a8 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
22   CoreFoundation                          0x19d6c70b8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 340
23   CoreFoundation                          0x19d6c5d88 __CFRunLoopRun + 828
24   CoreFoundation                          0x19d6c5968 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
25   GraphicsServices                        0x1e19bb4e0 GSEventRunModal + 164
26   UIKitCore                               0x19fb38edc -[UIApplication _run] + 888
27   UIKitCore                               0x19fb38518 UIApplicationMain + 340
28   tecommobile.iOS                         0x1065265ec xamarin_UIApplicationMain + 60
29   tecommobile.iOS                         0x104483988 wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_xamarin_UIApplicationMain_int_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr_ + 152
30   tecommobile.iOS                         0x1043d4edc UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr + 21417692 (UIApplication.cs:58)
31   tecommobile.iOS                         0x1043d5000 UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string + 21417984 (UIApplication.cs:84)
32   tecommobile.iOS                         0x10307a840 tecommobile_iOS_Application_Main_string__ + 1124416 (<unknown>:1)
33   tecommobile.iOS                         0x1034a8810 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 272
34   tecommobile.iOS                         0x1063bf44c mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 54883404 (mini-runtime.c:3191)
35   tecommobile.iOS                         0x10646bd88 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 55590280 (object.c:3220)
36   tecommobile.iOS                         0x106470ffc mono_runtime_exec_main_checked + 55611388 (object.c:5288)
37   tecommobile.iOS                         0x1063a3c40 mono_jit_exec + 54770752 (driver.c:1328)
38   tecommobile.iOS                         0x10653ba70 xamarin_main + 56441456 (monotouch-main.m:490)
39   tecommobile.iOS                         0x10307524c main + 1102412 (main.m:186)
40   dyld   

Does this mean that we need to modify FinishedLaunching() in AppDelegate.cs to move some of the tasks to a worker thread? Please note that we didn't have the problem in previous releases. We are unable to reproduce the crash so far.

You are unable to reproduce this crash in the exact same device?

Also it should be the latest OS version iOS17.4.1.

Unfortunately the symbolicate didn't show the managed code crashes. However, I have found the exception without the tool.
I understand that there is apk.mSYM, mono-symbolicate. I wonder how to use mono-symbolicate on any platform along with the matching mSYM files.
